# How to specify the path name in Named Credential

Tags: apexrest, namedcredentials

I have created Named Credential for a SharePoint Site successfully. I am trying to call the Named Credential with path specified through Apex. I am having trouble in specifying the path name. For example the path is  `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Salesforce Test List')/items?$select=ID,Title`. How do I specify that in the below code?

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Content-Length', '512');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json; odata=verbose');
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Salesforce Test List')/items?$select=ID,Title');
req.setTimeout(1200);
HttpResponse response = http.send(req);
System.debug(response.getBody());
```

Comment: What is this `getbytitle('Salesforce Test List')` in your URL?

Comment: It will return the Sharepoint List Items.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35796.sharepoint-2013-using-rest-api-for-selecting-filtering-sorting-and-pagination-in-sharepoint-list.aspx

Comment: You have a space and extra slash in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to call the Named Credential by sepcifying the path name.

Named Credential: https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/testsfint

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As per Salesforce [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_define.htm&type=0), The  named credential should be URL or root URL of the callout endpoint. Must begin with http:// or https://. Can include a path but not a query string. Examples:

- http://my_endpoint.example.com
- https://my_endpoint.example.com/secure/payroll

You can, however, append a query string and a specific path in the callout definition’s reference to the named credential. For example, an Apex callout could reference the named credential “My_Payroll_System” as follows.

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Payroll_System/paystubs?format=json');
```

In your case named credential should be like this.

```
https://yourdoamin.sharepointonline.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'AccountTest\')
```

And in apex you can pass the parameters as below.

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:SPO_Integration/items?$select=ID,Title');
```